# How to fix jest-preview not loading scss module styles

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using react-testing-library to write tests, and have been attempting to add the npm package `jest-preview` to visually preview the tests in a separate browser. However, none of my styles are being applied for some reason.

[jest-preview example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSOoQ.png)

I followed the steps, which the jest-preview docs listed to use with css modules:

jest.config.js
[jest config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTcIN.png)

Comment: Please create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Show the code and more details

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.